# How can i change my region/country but without putting a card to pay?

Tags: ios-appstore

How can i change my region/country but without putting a card to pay?

Comment: By changing, you mean creating a new/additional iTS account in another region?

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a new account in the new region via the app store and select payment option none.